# How to override toString method in Scala and replace it with a dynamic text

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to override the toString method in Scala. It has to return the time passed since an instance of the class is created. The time passed is computed in timePassed() method.

I have no idea on how to force the toString method to execute the timePassed method and generate an appropriate results when I call it.

Comment: Did you override `toString` on your custom class?

Comment: Sure. I can easily do something like`override def toString = "The status of the object is ...`. But it has to be dynamic. Something like `override def toString = s"The LED has a status of $internalTime."` where internalTime is the output of the method `timePassed`.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to let others know that your doubt concerned string interpolation rather than overriding a method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`toString` isn't magic, it's free to call whatever methods it wants, have local variables, etc.

```
override def toString = s"The LED has a status of ${timePassed()}."
```

or

```
override def toString = {
  val internalTime = timePassed()
  s"The LED has a status of $internalTime."
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the `{}` around `timePassed()`.